# How to generate a datetime in model using flutter freezed package

Tags: flutter, dart, model, flutter-freezed

I have this freezed part

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
part 'user_model.freezed.dart';
part 'user_model.g.dart';

@freezed
class UserModel with _$UserModel {
  factory UserModel({
    required String id,
    @Default('') String uniqueId,
    @Default(DateTime.now()) DateTime dob,

  }) = _UserModel;

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$UserModelFromJson(json);
}
```

But am not able to generate the required file due to **DateTime.now()**.

if I do something like this:

```
factory UserModel({
        required String id,
        @Default('') String uniqueId,
        required DateTime dob,
    
      }) = _UserModel;
```

it will work but I have to manually edit the generated data to this:

```
dob: (json['dob'] as Timestamp?)?.toDate() ?? DateTime.now()
```

from

```
dob: DateTime.parse(json['dob'] as String),
```

I can't keep manually editing it all time.

Please how do I generate the model class including Datetime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to manually add serialization logic in your freezed model class.

In this specific situation, you need firestore timestamp serialization logic.

Just add

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

class TimestampSerializer implements JsonConverter<DateTime, dynamic> {
  const TimestampSerializer();

  @override
  DateTime fromJson(dynamic timestamp) => timestamp.toDate();

  @override
  Timestamp toJson(DateTime date) => Timestamp.fromDate(date);
}
```

and add `TimestampSerializer()` annotation for your DateTime property like this.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
part 'user_model.freezed.dart';
part 'user_model.g.dart';

@freezed
class UserModel with _$UserModel {
  factory UserModel({
    required String id,
    @Default('') String uniqueId,
    @TimestampSerializer() required DateTime dob,

  }) = _UserModel;

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$UserModelFromJson(json);
}
```

and then finally run build runner. You are good to go.

Hope it helps! Happy coding:)

Comment: this did not solve the problem

Comment: Are you getting any error? I'm using this for all of my projects.

Comment: yes am getting error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: see this https://prnt.sc/nsJRyrC9r-4J

Comment: look at the screenshot

Comment: My bad, you need to add @ before `TimestampSerializer()` like `@TimestampSerializer()`. Please try this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250224/discussion-between-tpp-and-bharath-t).

Comment: I dropped a message

Comment: probably you also need to add `as DateTime` at the end of fromJson method

Comment: This worked for me! Don't forget to run the code runner!